# Why the decrypted hash does not match the encrypted hash in the signature?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sha256, cryptojs

From my understanding, the hash that is encrypted in the Signature by the private key, should match the hash of the payload. I have written a small node program to test out that concept but the hash fails to match even though the verification passed.

Below is what I have tried.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

// generate some stub keys for the test program
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'spki',
        format: 'pem',
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs8',
        format: 'pem',
    },
});

// the payload to be signed
const payload = 'helloWorld';

// create the signature
const signatureFunction = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
signatureFunction.write(payload);
signatureFunction.end();
const signature = signatureFunction.sign(privateKey, 'base64');

// verify the signature
const verifyFunction = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
verifyFunction.write(payload);
verifyFunction.end();

// the result is "true" which means my public key can verify the encrypted hash
console.log(verifyFunction.verify(publicKey, signature, 'base64'));

// decrypt and check what is the hash
const decryptedHash = crypto.publicDecrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from(signature, 'base64'));
console.log(`decryptedHash: ${decryptedHash.toString('base64')}`);

// manually generate the hash
const manualHash = crypto
    .createHash('SHA256')
    .update(payload)
    .digest('base64');
console.log(`manualHash: ${manualHash}`);
```

Below is the output:

```
true
decryptedHash: MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIBHU3cNX4IIpaNv9ImtuHCqsAY0HalTaT2Xh3IGAaErD
manualHash: EdTdw1fggilo2/0ia24cKqwBjQdqVNpPZeHcgYBoSsM=
```

My question is why the `decryptedHash` does not match the `manualHash` ?

Comment: The RSA signature isn't done on the full payload but on the (SHA-256) hash of the payload due to performance (RSA will getting very low on huge data). The signature itself is the result of some calculations and has nothing to do anymore with a hash, it is just a value. So calculating a hash manually will get a different result as the ("decrypted") signature. Btw: the decryption in an RSA private-public-key environment would be done with the private key. So the conclusion would be: a signature is not a hash.

Comment: Hi @MichaelFehr. Yup I know the signature is not a hash. But I think if you decrypt the signature, the content should be the hash of the payload. I am still learning my way, do correct me if I am wrong.
I have also posted an update below, I manage to match the hash of the payload now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I manage to find out why.. apparently `decryptedHash` is not really the actual hash value. I need to go to https://lapo.it/asn1js/ to convert it. I am not very well-verse in that area but I manage to find some clue by looking at this post https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80768/openssl-extract-hash-algorithm-from-signature-data-pkcs1-v-1-5

It seems that the `decryptedHash` is in DER ANS1 format.

Added 3 more lines to my program and I am able to match the `manualHash`

```
const valueGotFromLapoSite = '11D4DDC357E0822968DBFD226B6E1C2AAC018D076A54DA4F65E1DC8180684AC3';
const myHash = Buffer.from(valueGotFromLapoSite, 'hex').toString('base64');
console.log(`myHash: ${myHash}`);
```

Output:

```
true
decryptedHash: MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIBHU3cNX4IIpaNv9ImtuHCqsAY0HalTaT2Xh3IGAaErD
manualHash: EdTdw1fggilo2/0ia24cKqwBjQdqVNpPZeHcgYBoSsM=
myHash: EdTdw1fggilo2/0ia24cKqwBjQdqVNpPZeHcgYBoSsM=
```